# C# MySQL table list

Tags: c#, mysql

I am fairly new and I'm working on a project, however I can't get it to display data or figure out what's wrong or what I did wrong. Any help would be awesome. As I said I'm pretty new and still walking my way through this.

```
public class loadData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LOAD1 { get; set; }
    public string LOAD2{ get; set; }
    public string LOAD3 { get; set; }
    public string LOAD4 { get; set; }
    public string constructString { get; set; }

    public List<loadData> Select()
    {
        const string query = "SELECT * FROM data.dataload";
        string constring = constructString;

        //Create a list to store the result
        var list = new List<loadData>();

        //Open connection

        //Create Command
        MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        try
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase))
            {
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new loadData
                    {
                        ID = int.Parse(dataReader["ID"].ToString()),
                        LOAD1 = dataReader["LOAD1"].ToString(),
                        LOAD2 = dataReader["LOAD2"].ToString(),
                        LOAD3 = dataReader["LOAD3"].ToString(),
                        LOAD4 = dataReader["LOAD4"].ToString(),
                    });
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();

                //close Connection
                conDatabase.Close();

                //return list to be displayed
                return list;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return list;
        }
        finally { conDatabase.Close(); }

    }

    public void Display(List<loadData> list)
    {
        foreach (var load in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}:\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n",
                load.ID,
                load.LOAD1,
                load.LOAD2,
                load.LOAD3,
                load.LOAD4));
        }
    }
    /// CALL
    //MYSQL
    loadData data = new loadData();
    data.constructString = "datasource=dbt;port=8888;username=UNAME;password=PW;";
    data.Display(data.Select());
}
```

(*From comments given by OP*), the error is :

> {"Connection must be valid and open."} An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred

Comment: What's the error you're getting, and what're you expecting to achieve?

Comment: First step  catch  {throw;} instead of return the list and we will see what is your problem. Also you don't need to Dispose MySqlCommand your should wrap you MySqlConnection in using.

Comment: {"Connection must be valid and open."} An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred

Comment: A notice to your code. `MySqlConnection` is disposal, so instead of your try/catch/finally you can use a using statement there too.

Comment: I added the error text provided into the question. Why are the last three lines of code outside any function ?

Comment: I recommend making the connection object within the class scope, static, and either private or public; that way the properties of the connection object are the same over all instances of the class, regardless of how many times it has been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `conDatabase.Open()`. Do that before you try to execute `cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();` and you'll be fine